# How to load a JSON file in Meteor client or change Meteor.settings in server side to be available for clients

Tags: json, meteor

I am running Meteor 0.7.2 and want to load a `JSON` file in the client side. I have placed a `JSON` file in `/private` folder in the app root directory and it is loaded in server side without errors using following code:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(Assets.getText("myjson.json"));
```

But I want to do the same thing in client side too. When the app is loaded in client side, I want to load a `JSON` file at client side. Or if that `JSoN` loading is not possible then I want to update/assign value in `Meteor.settings.pulbic` in the server side and that update needs to be available to clients. (I read the Meteor documentation and refer several other resources, but couldn't figure out a way to do that.)

Can anybody have an idea on following things?

- Where to place a file to be loaded in client side (same like `/private` folder for server)
- What method should used to read that file (if there is a place for a `JSON` to store)
- Or is there a way to update `Meteor.settings.public` from server side when it is loaded and available to clents

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make files accessible on the client, put it in `/public`.

For example, if you create a file `/public/foo.json`, it will be accessible at `//server:port/foo.json`. You can load this file using any standard HTTP and AJAX methods, including Meteor's built-in [`HTTP.get`](http://docs.meteor.com/#http_get).