# How to grab the content of a file with a form in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to fetch the content of a JSON file with a form in a Meteor client but instead of the file content the console display `C:\fakepath\test.json`.

Content of the file :

```
{"1420416000":{"DT":[{"type":"lg","pct":1,"price":2.9486,"ex":"p"}]}}
```

If I change the value of the variable data to `event.target.collection.value`, with `collection` the name of the html text `input`, then the console display the text string entered in the form.

So why is it not working with the file ?

main.html

```
<body>
        {{> upload}}
</body>

<template name="upload">
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="collection">      
      <input type="file" name="files" multiple> 
      <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
</template>
```

main.js

```
Template.upload.events({

  'submit form': function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      data = event.target.files.value;
      console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Thank you,

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)
"File inputs' value attribute contains a DOMString that represents the path to the selected file(s)."

Comment: Oh, I see, but what would be the solution to insert file content in a collection from a client ? or at least grab the data.

Comment: I'm not sure. You could read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498357/how-to-load-a-json-file-in-meteor-client-or-change-meteor-settings-in-server-sid
What I would probably do is load the file and then have the server use it

Comment: @RenaudAubert is on the right track. For security reasons the client is not allowed access to the contents of the file, but the server receives it and can do whatever it wants with the data (like insert into a collection)

Comment: Thanks, I will consider also packages like `yogiben:autoform-file` and `ostrio:autoform-files` that handle files upload with autoform.